# Why does my code shows error when i Click the button

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning javascript. I am creating my notes app, but it's showing error to me. Please help to solve it.

```
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt").value;
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  notes.push(addTxt);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
  addTxt.value = "";
  console.log(notes);
  console.log("clicked");
})
```

Comment: *"but its showing error to me"* ? What error? Please read [mcve], then [edit] - and if you missed it, take a [tour].

Comment: You issue is that you use `notes.push(addTxt);` instead of `notesObj.push(addTxt);` - just because `notes` might be  either undefined or a String — depending on LS data exists or not.

Comment: You also need to use `notesObj` when saving back to local storage.

Answer (score 1):

You should be pushing onto `notesObj`, and stringifying that when saving back to `localStorage`.

Also, `addTxt` is a string, not the input element. To clear out the input element, you need to set the vaslue of the element, not the string.

```js
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt").value;
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  noteObjs.push(addTxt);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  document.getElementById("addTxt").value = "";
  console.log(notes);
  console.log("clicked");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments: [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) into the parsed Array, not into the LS retrieved String.

Here's a nicer remake:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);

// Task:

const EL_add = EL("#addBtn");
const EL_txt = EL("#addTxt");

EL_add.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  // Prevent default browser action
  evt.preventDefault(); 

  // Trim your values from spaces!
  const addTxt = EL_txt.value.trim(); 

  // No text, do nothing
  if (!addTxt) return; 
  
  // Get nodes from LS or fallback to empty Array
  const notesArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.notes || "[]");

  // Add note
  notesArr.push(addTxt);

  // Save note
  localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify(notesArr);

  // Reset input value
  EL_txt.value = ""; 
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, notes is a string, which is fine. But is notesObj an array or an object? if it notes is null, it is an array, but otherwise it is an object. This inconsistency makes `notes.push(addTxt)` which is only available to array. When there is stuff in localStorage, there is no `push` function for object, so it will make an error.
To fix, make a property on the notes object, such as 'data', which you can then do `notesObj.data.push(txt)`, also, when the object is null, turn it into a `{data:[]}`

Comment: LS returns always a String, or `undefined` if the LS property was not found. Not an Object. You only get JS *primitives* after parsing the JSON String.

Comment: he initializes it to an empty array when the local storage item isn't found. So I think we can clearly presume that it's always supposed to be an array.